# How to display base64 string as a pdf in lightning component

Tags: salesforce, salesforce-lightning

i have a requirement where i need to display Base64 string as PDF in lightning component without saving that string as file or attachment in salesforce.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a 3rd party Javascript library that can generate PDF on the client side.

**Example with [jsPDF](https://rawgit.com/MrRio/jsPDF/master/docs/index.html)**

Define a Blob and insert in in a `<iframe>` :

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jspdf/1.5.3/jspdf.debug.js" integrity="sha384-NaWTHo/8YCBYJ59830LTz/P4aQZK1sS0SneOgAvhsIl3zBu8r9RevNg5lHCHAuQ/" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<iframe id=iframe></iframe>

<script>
    var doc = new jsPDF();
    doc.text("Hello World", 35, 25);
    var blob = doc.output( 'blob' )
    var file = new File( [blob], 'a_name.pdf', { type: 'application/pdf' } )
    iframe.src = URL.createObjectURL( file )
</script>
```